# How do you convert "Wtihin group" in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have this SQL code and have to convert to BigQuery.

```
listagg(lov.value, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY lov.value) disc.name
```

I've found that I can replace listagg with string_agg() or array_agg() but has no clue how to convert the whole things. Any tips articles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [STRING_AGG()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#string_agg).

```
STRING_AGG(lov.value, ';' ORDER BY lov.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply use `string_agg()`:

```
string_agg(lov.value, ';' order by lov.value desc)
```

If you are using BigQuery, consider using arrays instead (i.e. `array_agg()`).  Arrays are usually much more convenient than strings.